# Alertas con Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio

Tengo un formulario en  Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64 bits) Versión 17.1.1
Uso VB y ASP
Mi script es el siguiente, mismo que coloqué en el head de mi página Registrar.aspx

```
 <script>
    function bien() {
        var lblid = document.getElementById('<%=Lblerrorsap.ClientID%>').innerText;

        swal({
            title: "!Exito!",
            text: "" + lblid,
            type: "success",

            confirmButtonColor: "#51FF00",
            confirmButtonText: "Continuar",
        },
            function () {
                window.location.href = '~/Registrar.aspx';
            });
    }

    function mal() {
        var lbae = document.getElementById('<%=Lblerrorsap.ClientID%>').innerText;
        swal("!Error!", "" + lbae, "error")
    }
    function info() {
        var lbae = document.getElementById('<%=Lblerrorsap.ClientID%>').innerText;
        swal("!Atención!", "" + lbae, "info")
    }
</script>
```

En el scriptmanager tengo lo siguiente, éste lo tengo dentro del form pero fuera del panel, ya lo he colocado también dentro del panel

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnableScriptGlobalization="true" EnableCdn="true">
            <Scripts>

                <asp:ScriptReference Name="MsAjaxBundle" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="bootstrap" />

                  <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="MenuStandards.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="GridView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="DetailsView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="TreeView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebParts.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="Focus.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebFormsBundle" />
                                    
            </Scripts>

        </asp:ScriptManager>
```

En el body mi formulario  tiene más paneles pero básicamente funcionan igual

```
<form id="main" runat="server" style="width: 80%">
<div>
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="P_actualizar" Visible="false">
<asp:Label ID="Lblerrorsap" runat="server" Text="" ForeColor="White"></asp:Label>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-2">
                            <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Sociedad" Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlSociedadActualizar" CssClass="form-control">
                                <asp:ListItem Value="SBO_Alianza">Alianza</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="SBO_FGE">F G Electrical</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="SBO_MANUFACTURING">Manufacturing</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="SBO_Pruebas">Pruebas</asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-3">
                            <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Razón social" Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" CssClass="form-control" Enabled="false" ID="txtRSactualizar"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-3">
                            <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Código de cliente" Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" CssClass="form-control" Enabled="false" ID="txtCardcodeActualizar"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-3">
                            <asp:Label runat="server" Text="RFC" Font-Bold="true">    </asp:Label>
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" CssClass="form-control" Enabled="false" ID="txtRFCActualizar"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-3">
                            <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Correo" Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" CssClass="form-control" ID="txtCorreoActualizar"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-3">
                            <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Password" Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" CssClass="form-control" ID="txtPassActualizar"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-3">
                            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnActualizar" CssClass="btn btn-primary" Text="Actualizar" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </asp:Panel>
 </div>
    </form>
```

En la lógica, Registrar.aspx.vb tengo lo siguiente
Las líneas comentadas son alertas que mostraba anteriormente pero decidí darles mejor formato pero actualmente de ninguna forma se muestran y no se por qué

```
Private Sub btnActualizar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnActualizar.Click
    Try
        ExpSQL = "update ocrd setE_Mail ='" & txtCorreoActualizar.Text & "' , Password='" & txtPassActualizar.Text & "' where cardcode ='" & txtCardcodeActualizar.Text & "' and cardtype='C'"
        claseSQL.InserDatos(sError, ExpSQL, ddlSociedadActualizar.SelectedValue)

        Lblerrorsap.Text = "Actualizacion correcta "

        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, GetType(Page), "alerta", "<script>bien()</script>", False)
        'ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, GetType(Page), "alerta", "<script>alert('Actualización correcta')</script>", False)
        'Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx")
    Catch ex As Exception
        Lblerrorsap.Text = "Error al actualizar " & ex.Message & " - " & sError
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, GetType(Page), "alerta", "<script>mal()</script>", False)
        ' ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, GetType(Page), "alerta", "<script>alert('No se pudieron actualizar los datos\n Favor de intentar nuevmente o contactar con atención a clientes')</script>", False)
    End Try

End Sub
```

Esas alertas deberían mostrar algo como la siguiente imagen, en la compilación no marca ningún error y con los puntos de interrupción se supone que si se ejecutan pero no se muestran.
¿Alguien tiene alguna idea de porqué no se ven? o alguna solución

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]